# opepyxl and 2D area chart

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to create a 2D area chart based from data in an excel file I generate in python.
I have followed the tutorial https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/area.html#d-area-charts.
My problem is quite simple, the data are not ordered in the same way the example given in the tutorial. They are transposed.

[image]

With data ordered that way, I didn't find so far the correct modification in the Reference method:

```
cats = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_row=7)
data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=7)
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(cats)
```

All my trials gave an incorrect area graph.
Any suggestion?

Thanks.
Sebastien

Answer (score 0):

You dont say what a correct chart is, but the default chart would probably be something like the following. Showing chart creation as adding each different series from the data in range A1:G3.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import (
    AreaChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

chart = AreaChart()
chart.title = "Area Chart"
chart.style = 13
chart.x_axis.title = 'Number'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Batch'

# nseries x-axis OR add as category see below
ndata = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=7, max_row=1)
nseries = Series(ndata, title_from_data=ndata)
chart.append(nseries)

# first series
s1data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=7, max_row=2)
series1 = Series(s1data, title_from_data=s1data)
series1.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "00000"
series1.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "ff9900"
chart.append(series1)

# second series
s2data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=3, max_col=7, max_row=3)
series2 = Series(s2data, title_from_data=s2data)
series2.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "00000"
series2.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "ffff00"
chart.append(series2)

### Add 'Number' as category if preferred. Enable these two lines and disable the number series above
# cats = Reference(ws, min_col=1, max_col=7, min_row=1, max_row=1)
# chart.set_categories(cats)

ws.add_chart(chart, "A5")

wb.save("area2D.xlsx")
```

[image: Example Chart]

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. I'll try your solution.
I made progress using the from_rows paramter like this:
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)